# Is there a way to get vim plugin for Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, remix, vim

I use vim regularly for coding.
I love the way remix gives all packages to develop on the browser, but it is convenient to go arrow keys and not being able to use vim shortcuts to delete.

Is there a way to add vim to Remix IDE?

Answer (score 2):

You'll lose out on completions, but Wasavi enables you to use any text field like a vim buffer: https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi

Answer (score 1):

So far https://github.com/NickTomlin/pocketvim is working great. Had to disable vimium on remix.ethereum.org